# Beginner: loss.backwards() doesn't work if input had no impact on output

Tags: pytorch

I am a beginner with pytorch and have the following problem.

I want to optimize a complex problem that uses torch.min() multiple times, but even with a simple toy example I can't get it to work. My code has these lines:

```
output = net(input)
loss = g(output)
loss = torch.min(loss, torch.ones(1))
loss.backward()
```

To minimize this loss the net should ascertain that the output minimizes g:R^2->R. Here g is a very simple function that has a zero at {-1,-2} and if I delete the third line the neural network finds the solution just fine. However with the posted code and bad initial weights the minimum is attained by 1. This leads to the backward() function not updating the weights and no learning happening at all over arbitrary many epochs.

Is there a way to detect/fix this behaviour in more complex cases? My task uses the minimum function multiple times and in more complex ways, so I think it would be quite hard to track every single one and ascertain that learning actually takes place.

Edit: If I start the optimizer multiple times it rarely happens that the optimization works just fine (e.g. converges to {-1,-2}). My interpretation is that in those cases the inital weights randomly lead to the minimum beeing attained in the first component.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code:

```
output = net(input)
loss_fn = torch.min
y_hat = g(output)
y = torch.ones(1)
loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)
loss.backward()
```

<sub>You wrote:</sub>

> This leads to the backward() function not updating the weights and no learning happening at all over arbitrary many epochs.

Once we calculate the loss we call `loss.backward()`. The `loss.backward()` will calculate the gradients automatically. Gradients are needed in the next phase, when we use the `optimizer.step()` function to improve our model parameters (weights).

You need to have the optimizer something like this:

```
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
```

Since PyTorch training loop can be 100 lines of code, I will just reference some material in [here](https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/pytorch/) perfect for beginners.

Comment: As I stated above the optimizer works when I leave out the minimum function. I define an optimizer, zero the gradient and use the step function. Since it works when I leave out the 3rd line above I don't think the problem lies there.